# Which require packages for $.ajax call to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What requires do i have to make to run the following in node. I tried a few things with no luck, like:

```
var $ = require("jquery")
```

which leads to

```
Thrown:
TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
```

Here is my code (I'm running this in cli with node):

```
var $ = require("jquery")
require("console")
function download(data, handler = null) {
  var url = "http://localhost:3000";
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success');
    },
  });
}

download('{"number":"1009"}')
```

Comment: I don't think jQuery works in the nodejs environment for http calls. You need to use http module or some wrapper around it like request/request promise etc

Comment: This error might come due to incorrect position of the script in the page. Have you tried keeping this script at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use express in node for downloading data on API routes.
What you did with Jquery would be for the front end

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.get('/3000', (request, response) => {
  //this is where you would run your function to download
  response.send(/*downloaded data*/).status(200);
};
```